# Nice alignment across nodes in logic proof trees typeset with forest

Tags: forest, trees, logic, proof-package

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412502/169189), user cfr offers the following code which gives output as in the following image:

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\forestset{
  declare toks={from}{},
  declare toks register={claim},
  claim=,
  ll proof/.style={
    for tree={math content},
    before typesetting nodes={
      if claim={}{}{
        replace by/.process={Rw{claim}{[##1, math content, append]}},
        no edge,
        before computing xy={l'=2\baselineskip},
      },
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        content/.process={ OR OSl+tt= ? w  w3 {content}{tempcounta}{from}{}{}{(##1)}{##2.\quad ##1\quad ##3} }
      }
    },
    where n children=1{!1.no edge, before computing xy={!1.l'=\baselineskip}}{},
    close/.style={label=below:\textsf{x}},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ll proof,
  claim=\vdash ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))
  [ \lnot ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))    
    [ (p\lor (q\land r)) , from=1
      [ \lnot ((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)) , from=1
        [ p , from=2
          [ \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
            [ \lnot p , from=6
              [ \lnot q , from=6, close
          ]]]
          [ \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
            [1 \lnot p , from=7
            [1 \lnot r , from=7, close
        ]]]]
        [ (q\land r) , from=2
          [1 q , from=5
            [1 r , from=5
              [1 \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=14
                  [1 \lnot q , from=14, close
              ]]]
              [1 \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=15
                  [1 \lnot r , from=15, close
  ]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: A proof tree where each node has a line number, a quad space, a formula, a quad space and a justification]

I am wondering if anyone knows how to modify the code to produce output as in the following image:

[image: A proof tree where the line numbers, formulas and justifications on branches are horizontally aligned]
One approach I can think of is storing the widths of each of the widest line number, formula, and justification along each branch, and then wrapping the content of each node on the branch in a three-column tabular where the column widths are fixed to these maximum widths. Then the position of the anchors of the nodes would be set to the north of the formula column so that the lines between branches are drawn to the centres of the formulas.

A significantly less elegant but much easier approach would be to have multiline tabulars containing all of the formulas on a branch (i.e. one for the formulas numbered 1, 2, 3; another for 4; another for 5, 8, 11; and so on). But I would like to avoid an approach like this which would require significant changes to the tree itself rather than its style.

Unfortunately I don't really have the technical expertise at present to even know where to start on actually implementing a more elegant solution, so I'd appreciate whatever help is on offer.

### UPDATE

Here's a partial answer which involves processing the content into a one-line tabular with three columns, one for the line number, one for the wff and another for the justification:

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\forestset{
  declare toks={from}{},
  declare toks register={claim},
  claim=,
  ll proof/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      if claim={}{}{
        replace by/.process={Rw{claim}{[##1, math content, append]}},
        no edge,
        before computing xy={l'=2\baselineskip},
      },
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        content/.process={ OR OSl+tt= ? w  w3 {content}{tempcounta}{from}{}{}{(##1)}{\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{1em}cp{1em}}##2. & \ensuremath{##1} & \ensuremath{##3}\\\end{tabular}} }
      }
    },
    where n children=1{!1.no edge, before computing xy={!1.l'=\baselineskip}}{},
    close/.style={label=below:\textsf{x}},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ll proof,
  claim=\vdash ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))
  [ \lnot ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))    
    [ (p\lor (q\land r)) , from=1
      [ \lnot ((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)) , from=1
        [ p , from=2
          [ \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
            [ \lnot p , from=6
              [ \lnot q , from=6, close
          ]]]
          [ \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
            [1 \lnot p , from=7
            [1 \lnot r , from=7, close
        ]]]]
        [ (q\land r) , from=2
          [1 q , from=5
            [1 r , from=5
              [1 \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=14
                  [1 \lnot q , from=14, close
              ]]]
              [1 \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=15
                  [1 \lnot r , from=1500, close
  ]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The above makes it so that the centres of the formulas are horizontally aligned. Thus we obtain

[image: aligned formula centres]

instead of

[image: misaligned formula centres]

as in the original code. This already improves legibility and aesthetics.

The missing piece of the puzzle is to organise things such that the widths of the formula columns at 17. and 19. are set to the width of the formula column at 15. so that the line numbers and justifications are horizontally aligned as well. (And similarly throughout the tree.)

I think that [this answer by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280525/169189) hints towards a way of calculating the width of each formula. But I don't know how to store the widths and then select the widest appropriate one for each set of formulas.

### Another update

I created a `fwidth` tok that gets passed to the width of the formula column. Now everything is nicely aligned, but the trade-off is that the user needs to set this key for every node on the tree. The best way to find out what it should be set to is to plug the widest formula of a branch into the code

```
\newlength{\myl}
\settowidth{\myl}{formula goes here}
\the\myl
```

and then set `fwidth` to that length for every formula in the branch. See the example code below:

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\forestset{
  declare toks={from}{},
  declare toks={fwidth}{},
  declare toks register={claim},
  claim=,
  ll proof/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      if claim={}{}{
        replace by/.process={Rw{claim}{[##1, math content, append]}},
        no edge,
        before computing xy={l'=2\baselineskip},
      },
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        content/.process={ OR OSl+tt= ? w  Ow4 {content}{tempcounta}{from}{}{}{(##1)}{fwidth}{\begin{tabular}{p{1em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{##4}p{1em}}##2. & \ensuremath{##1} & \ensuremath{##3}\\\end{tabular}} }
      }
    },
    where n children=1{!1.no edge, before computing xy={!1.l'=\baselineskip}}{},
    close/.style={label=below:\textsf{x}},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ll proof,
  claim=\vdash ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))
  [ \lnot ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r))), fwidth=158.8pt    
    [ (p\lor (q\land r)) , from=1, fwidth=158.8pt
      [ \lnot ((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)) , from=1, fwidth=158.8pt
        [ p , from=2, fwidth=5.1pt
          [ \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3, fwidth=35.5pt
            [ \lnot p , from=6, fwidth=35.5pt
              [ \lnot q , from=6, close, fwidth=35.5pt
          ]]]
          [ \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3, fwidth=35.5pt
            [1 \lnot p , from=7, fwidth=35.5pt
            [1 \lnot r , from=7, close, fwidth=35.5pt
        ]]]]
        [ (q\land r) , from=2, fwidth=28.6pt
          [1 q , from=5, fwidth=28.6pt
            [1 r , from=5, fwidth=28.6pt
              [1 \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3, fwidth=40.5pt
                [1 \lnot p , from=14, fwidth=40.5pt
                  [1 \lnot q , from=14, close, fwidth=40.5pt
              ]]]
              [1 \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3, fwidth=40.5pt
                [1 \lnot p , from=15, fwidth=40.5pt
                  [1 \lnot r , from=1500, close, fwidth=40.5pt
  ]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Things look really nice now, but it would be considerably more convenient if `fwidth` could be calculated and set automatically. (It would also be nice to hide the overfull warnings that come from setting the line number and justification columns to a small fixed width.) I await someone with a deeper knowledge of TikZ and `forest` to show the way.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558411/align-edges-of-forest-to-center-of-column-in-node) is a variant using tabulars, so that at least the three columns are aligned. Unfortunately anchoring the nodes to the north of the formula column, rather the node of the table, is just what I haven't been able to resolve.

Comment: @lemontree Ah, I see we're basically trying to obtain the same output! As far as your solution with tabulars goes, have you tried setting the line number and justification columns to the same fixed width? I think this would make it so the middle of each tabular would then be the middle of the formula column.

Comment: This actually is a great idea; I just tried it and it worked. Thank you! If you post that as an answer to my question, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: @lemontree No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: You can just use `align=<tabular column specification>` rather than `\begin{tabular}...` because `forest`'s `align` is actually a tabular specification anyway.(`align=c` is making a single column tabular etc.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, I read that one can use `align` in that way while I was researching. However I wasn't sure how to implement it. Using `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` in an arg in `content/.process` was more apparent to me. If you can explain how to use `align` instead, I'd be very interested to know.

Comment: You just put your `align` in as normal and then use `&` appropriately in the `content/.process` wrap. Example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variation on the `tabular`/`align` idea which automatically determines the width of the central column (for the wff).

```
% ref.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570449/

\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering $}p{#1}<{$}}
\forestset{
  declare toks={from}{},
  declare toks register={claim},
  declare boolean={align me}{0},
  declare dimen={my width}{0pt},
  declare dimen register={lmeas},
  lmeas/.pgfmath=width("99."),
  declare dimen register={rmeas},
  rmeas/.pgfmath=width("(99)"),
  claim=,
  ll proof/.style={
    for tree={
      math content,
    },
    for root=align me,
    before typesetting nodes={
      if claim={}{}{
        replace by/.process={Rw{claim}{[##1, math content, append]}},
        no edge,
        before computing xy={l'=2\baselineskip},
      },
    },
    where n children=1{!1.no edge, before computing xy={!1.l'=\baselineskip},}{},
    for root={align me},
    where n children>=2{
      for children={align me}}{},
    before packing={
      tempcountb'=0,
      where align me={%
        tempcountb'+=1,
        tempdima/.max={>{OOw2+d}{max x}{min x}{##1-##2}}{%
          walk and save={temptoksa}{current,
             until={> O_=!{n children}{1}}{first,typeset node}}%
        },
        for nodewalk={load=temptoksa}{my width/.register=tempdima, typeset node}, 
      }{},
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        align=p{\foresteregister{lmeas}}C{\foresteoption{my width}}p{\foresteregister{rmeas}},
        content/.process={ OR OSl+tt= ? w  w3 {content}{tempcounta}{from}{}{}{(##1)}{##2.\quad & ##1\quad & ##3} },
        typeset node,
      }
    },
    close/.style={label=below:\textsf{x}},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ll proof,
  claim=\vdash ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))
  [ \lnot ((p\lor (q\land r))\to((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)))    
    [ (p\lor (q\land r)) , from=1
      [ \lnot ((p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)) , from=1
        [ p , from=2
          [ \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
            [ \lnot p , from=6
              [ \lnot q , from=6, close
          ]]]
          [ \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
            [1 \lnot p , from=7
            [1 \lnot r , from=7, close
        ]]]]
        [ (q\land r) , from=2
          [1 q , from=5
            [1 r , from=5
              [1 \lnot (p\lor q) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=14
                  [1 \lnot q , from=14, close
              ]]]
              [1 \lnot (p\lor r) , from=3
                [1 \lnot p , from=15
                  [1 \lnot r , from=15, close
  ]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tableau-split-line-nos-with-alignment]

Sašo could make this faster in any case, but I'm out of practice, so somebody else may be able to do better, too. The fancy column specifier seemed to get entangled with `forest`'s parser. Hence the somewhat clunky approach. Like I say, somebody else will doubtless make it behave more politely.

Comment: Glorious, thank you. I'm excited to study how this works.

Comment: @solisoc I thought it would be enough to set the width of the middle column, but obviously that was a dumb assumption. You could get a slightly more compact tree by taking the maximum width of the wff numbers and justifications, but it didn't seem worth the trouble or compilation speed hit.